# How to Convert Table Data into xml format using sql with multiple sub nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table structure like below :

```
SELECT  
    [EmpID], [EmpName],
    [DeptName],
    [BirthDate] 
FROM
    [dbo].[Employees]
```

I want to convert this table data into XML and the final output will be like below:

```
<Employees>
    <Department DeptName="ABC"> 
        <Employee EmpID="1">
            <EmpName>Davolio</EmpName>
            <BirthDate>10/12/1989</BirthDate>
        </Employee>
        <Employee EmpID="2">
            <EmpName>Andrew</EmpName>    
            <BirthDate>05/02/1985</BirthDate>
        </Employee>
    </Department>
    <Department DeptName="DEF"> 
        <Employee EmpID="3">
            <EmpName>David</EmpName>
            <BirthDate>11/09/1982</BirthDate>
        </Employee> 
    </Department>`enter code here
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  [DeptName] 
        ,(  SELECT  [EmpID],
                    [EmpName],
                    [BirthDate] 
            FROM @table E
            WHERE   E.DeptName = D.DeptName
            FOR XML PATH ('Employee'),TYPE
        )
FROM    @table D
GROUP BY [DEPTNAME]
FOR XML PATH ('Department'),type,ROOT('Employees')
```

Comment: @saiv One tiny hint: If you want to have the `DeptName` and the `EmpID` as attributes (like in the given example), you must add an Alias `AS [@DeptName]` resp. `AS [@EmpID]`. And be aware, that XML will use the ISO8601 and therefore the date will look like `1982-09-11T00:00:00`