# How can I convert a hierarchical table to xml in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a requirement to transform the result of a query into an xml fragment using t-SQL.
My table/query looks like this:

```
[Col1]  [Col2]      [Col3]      qty
A       group1      mod1        5
A       group1      mod2        7
A       group1      NULL        12
A       group2      mod3        8
A       group2      mod4        5
A       group2      NULL        13
A       NULL        NULL        25
```

and the desired XML output should look like this

```
<A qty="25">
    <group1 qty="12">
        <mod1 qty="5"/>
        <mod2 qty="7"/>
    </group1>
    <group2 qty="13">
        <mod3 qty="8"/>
        <mod4 qty="5"/>
    </group2>
</A>
```

Is there a way to achieve this without pivoting the table and using dynamic sql which would be very messy

Comment: Try for xml path. Google xml sql server

Comment: This is a little similar to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36768199/1068246

Comment: @MuzafferGALATA. Thanks for the link. This addresses the nesting issue. I'm also trying to find a way to have the column value as the element name. But this doesn't seem possible

Comment: @MuzafferGALATA this is far from the question you linked to, for a VERY important point: The link provides a solution where the name of the column is the name of the node (which is the way FOR XML works), but in this case the OP want to build the XML in a way that the VALUEs become the name of the nodes. This is a huge different. In first glance it seems like a pivot/unpivot or a loop is required here.

Comment: You are right @RonenAriely.

Comment: Done! Without any loop or Pivot but I scan the table 3 times (once for each level)... Will publish in a min..

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Please confirm that this solve your need. We can next work on improving performance. It is important to have the right indexes

### DDL+DML

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T
GO

CREATE TABLE T(
    [Col1] VARCHAR(10),
    [Col2] VARCHAR(10),
    [Col3] VARCHAR(10),
    qty VARCHAR(10)
)
GO

INSERT T([Col1],[Col2],[Col3],qty) VALUES
('A', 'group1', 'mod1', 5 ),
('A', 'group1', 'mod2', 7 ),
('A', 'group1',  NULL , 12),
('A', 'group2', 'mod3', 8 ),
('A', 'group2', 'mod4', 5 ),
('A', 'group2', NULL  , 13),
('A',  NULL   , NULL  , 25)
GO

SELECT [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],qty 
FROM T
GO
```

### Solution

```
;with l1 as (
    SELECT COL1, qty
    FROM T
    where col2 is null and col3 is null
)
, l2 as (
    SELECT Col1, COL2, qty
    FROM T
    where col2 is not null and col3 is null
)
, l3 as (
    SELECT Col1, COL2, COL3, qty
    FROM T
    where col2 is not null and col3 is not null
)
, a1 as (
    SELECT COL2, X = STRING_AGG('<' + COL3 + ' qty="' + qty + '"/>' ,'') 
    FROM l3
    GROUP BY Col2
)
, a2 as (
    select X = '<' + a1.Col2 + ' qty="' + l2.qty + '">' + a1.X + '</' + a1.Col2 + '>', l2.Col1
    from a1 
    LEFT JOIN l2 on a1.Col2 = l2.Col2
)
select CONVERT(XML,
    '<' + l1.Col1 + ' qty="' + l1.qty + '">' + STRING_AGG(a2.X,'') + '</' + l1.Col1 + '>' 
)
from a2
left join l1 on l1.Col1 = a2.Col1
group by l1.Col1, l1.qty
GO
```

Note! at the end I convert the value to XML in order to check that the result fit. In production there is no reason for this step, which cost resources.

Answer (score 0):

@RonenAriely your solution inspired me. I've modified it a little. Because I could not run it.
My solution looks a little dirty and complicated and not elegant but the result is correct.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Col1 CHAR(1), Col2 CHAR(6), Col3 CHAR(4), qty INT);
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES ('A', 'group1', 'mod1', 5),
       ('A', 'group1', 'mod2', 7),
       ('A', 'group1', '', 12),
       ('A', 'group2', 'mod3', 8),
       ('A', 'group2', 'mod4', 5),
       ('A', 'group2', '', 13),
       ('A', '', '', 25);



WITH l1
  AS (SELECT Col1,
             Col2,
             SUM(qty) AS qty FROM @Tbl WHERE Col2 <> ''
         AND Col3 <> ''
         AND Col2 <> ''
       GROUP BY Col1,
                Col2),
  l2
  AS (SELECT Col2,
             SUM(qty) AS qty FROM @Tbl WHERE Col3 <> ''
       GROUP BY Col2),
  l3
  AS (SELECT Col2,
             Col3,
             SUM(qty) AS qty FROM @Tbl
       GROUP BY Col2,
                Col3),
  a1
  AS (SELECT Col2,
             '<' + Col3 + ' qty="' + CAST(qty AS VARCHAR(10)) + '"/>' AS c FROM l3 WHERE Col3 <> ''),

  a2
  AS (SELECT l1.Col1,
             '<' + aa.Col2 + ' qty="' + CAST(l2.qty AS VARCHAR(10)) + '">' +

             STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '' + c FROM a1 WHERE Col2 = aa.Col2
                 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '')
             + '</' + aa.Col2 + '>' AS c FROM a1 aa
        LEFT JOIN l1
          ON l1.Col2 = aa.Col2
        LEFT JOIN l2
          ON aa.Col2 = l2.Col2
       GROUP BY l1.Col1,
                aa.Col2,
                l2.qty)

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('<' + aa.Col1 + ' qty="' + CAST(l1.qty AS VARCHAR(10)) + '">'

    + STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '' + c FROM a2 WHERE Col1 = aa.Col1
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 0, '')
    + '</' + aa.Col1 + '>', '&amp;', '&'), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>') AS c

  FROM a2 aa
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Col1, SUM(qty) AS qty FROM l1 GROUP BY Col1) l1
    ON l1.Col1 = aa.Col1
GROUP BY aa.Col1,
         l1.qty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own post.

Thank you all for your help. In the end, I have implemented a solution using dynamic SQL as I have many blocks to process and I need a generic solution. My final code looks like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ' + 
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + qty + ' as ''' 
         + Col1 
         + ISNULL('/'+ Col2,'') 
         + ISNULL('/'+ Col3,'') 
         + '/@qty''' FROM T ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3 FOR XML PATH('')) 
      ,1,1,'') + ' FOR XML PATH('''')'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Unfortunately, it cannot be implemented as a function (which was my initial goal) because it requires a physical table and because of the string size limitation. This would also not work for a large dataset with many sublevels. I will have to live with it!